# Normal method or property?

Tags: python, django

Should the below be a normal model method or a property?

```
@property
def num_used_licenses(self):
    return len(CompanyUser.objects.filter(company_id=self.pk, activated_on__isnull=False)) # why doesn't count() work here?
```

Two points:

- It does do a DB query so it's not trivial performance-wise to call.
- It will never take any parameters

I was under the impress you would use a `property` if it's both trivial and doesn't take any parameters, but what should the above be, and why?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried using `.count()` and for whatever reason it was returning the queryset, so I just used length as a shorthand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access `num_used_licenses` as a Model attribute (without needing to call it like a method), use the `@property` decorator. If there is a chance you may change it to accept arguments in future, leave it as a method.

The Django [Model Methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods) docs include an example usage of the `@property` decorator:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        "Returns the person's full name."
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

And a link to the [glossary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/glossary/#term-property):

> **property**
>
> Also known as “managed attributes”, and a feature of Python since version 2.2. This is a neat way to implement attributes whose usage resembles attribute access, but whose implementation uses method calls.

Comment: thanks, though I'm still unclear as to which should be used for the above case, and why one would be more correct than the other. As for me, it's trivial whether it's called as `method` or `method()` -- I don't care myself.

Comment: There's no correct answer. It's a matter of taste, and properties are quite handy for stuff that you might want to change in the future. For example you might denormalize it into a model field for performance reasons, but whether this attribute is a property, a model field, or even a class constant is an internal implementation detail hidden from calling code. This makes refactoring easier.